# Given two tables created and populated as follows:

Tags: sql

Given two tables created and populated as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.envelope(id int, user_id int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.docs(idnum int, pageseq int, doctext varchar(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.envelope VALUES
  (1,1),
  (2,2),
  (3,3);

INSERT INTO dbo.docs(idnum,pageseq) VALUES
  (1,5),
  (2,6),
  (null,0);
```

What will the result be from the following query:

```
UPDATE docs SET doctext=pageseq FROM docs INNER JOIN envelope ON envelope.id=docs.idnum
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.docs
  WHERE id=envelope.id
);
```

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why don't you just run it and see for yourself what you get?

Comment: exactly my point. If you have any doubt then ask specifically.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and using `INNER JOIN` in an UPDATE statement is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bf0528aab1d301215cf7fb4aecfc056

Comment: wow its greate!

Answer (score 0):

you need this:
its o...just run and see result

```
 With t
 As(
 select * from
 docs INNER JOIN envelope ON  envelope.id=docs.idnum
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.docs WHERE id=envelope.id)

 Update docs
 Set docs.num
 From t
 Where docs.idnum=t.idnum
```

Comment: In fact the statements after data modifying and not selecting ringing any data. Therefore, if the the question to be formulated as what is the result of a series of DML statements the answer would be no data returned, only metadata and status information depending on the DBMS and settings

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bf0528aab1d301215cf7fb4aecfc056

Answer (score 0):

if `idnum` exist in `envelope` table then `UPDATE` command will update `doctext` (Set `doctext=pageseq`) column from `docs` table